# Draw a plane through a line parallel to the $x$-axis

Tags: analytic-geometry

Can someone help me with this problem? I bet it will be pretty easy for the most of you:

> Through the line $p$ draw a plane that is parallel to the $x$-axis,
>   where p is defined by: $x=5-2t, y=9t-1, z=-7t-2$.

Since it's parallel to the $x$-axis, I know that the equation of the plane will have this form: $By+Cz+D=0.$ I also know that there is a point that lies on the plane $P(5,2,0)$ and a vector $p(-2,1,3)$.

I don't know how to use this information, though. Any help?

Comment: Do you really mean to write $p=x$?

Comment: sorry i was to lazy to write it properly. i posted it like a picture now

Comment: That won't get you any good answers.

Comment: I think you changed the 3 equations of the line p.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the line p has equations:
$x = -2t + 5   $
$y = t + 2   $
$z = 3t   $

Let the equation of the plane be: $ax + by + cz = d$
Since it's parallel to the $x$ axis, $a=0$ and $d\ne0$ (you also found that).
Take any two points from your line e.g. $(5,2,0)$ and $(3,3,3)$.
Now put these two points into the plane equation:
$by + cz = d$
You get a system with 2 equations.

$b.2 + c.0 = d$
$b.3 + c.3 = d$

Solving it for $(b,c)$ you get $b=d/2$, $c=-d/6$.

So the equation of the plane becomes:

$(d/2) \cdot y - (d/6) \cdot z = d$

Multiply it by $6/d$ and you get the final equation: 
$3y-z=6$

Comment: I think the OP changed the equations of the line p after I wrote this answer.

Comment: no, they are correct. thanks a lot man, i owe you one :)